# Is a loop actually a circuit?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

If I have a single vertex with a self-loop. Do we call that a circuit? Because we "loop" around itself once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cycle in a graph is, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29),

> An edge set that has even degree at every vertex; also called an even edge set or, when taken together with its vertices, an even subgraph.

In your case, the single vertex has a degree of 2, which is even. Therefore the self-loop is a cycle in your graph.

Comment: Note that, generally, "cycle" and "circuit" have different meanings.

Answer (score 2):

I'd lean towards calling it a circuit.  However, when it comes to these technical and isolated cases, it's often best to simply choose whichever definition makes your work easiest to read.

The distinction between defining a loop as a circuit or not should be a very minor consideration in a larger body of work.  The larger body of work is what's important.  As long as we state our definition unambiguously and are consistent throughout, it's not a real problem.

To illustrate, if you go through my papers and look at the different ways I've defined a *Latin square*, you'll see that the definitions are inconsistent.  I just pick whichever definition makes the paper easiest to read.  I could use up the readers time in being consistent, but instead I just get to the real point of the paper.

However, in some cases these slight distinctions can matter.  For example, [*Counting loopy graphs with given degrees*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0080) by McKay and Greenhill, the distinction between loops contributing 1 or 2 to the degree of a vertex made a non-negligible difference in the case of asymptotic enumeration of graphs with a given degree sequence.  The author's responded to this situation by analysing both cases.