# Is a self-loop in directional graph considered as a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

This question seems similar to [Is a loop actually a circuit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354551/is-a-loop-actually-a-circuit) but it is different. The linked question refers to a undirectional graph so the vertex of the self-loop ends up with degree 2. Also the linked question talks about circuits which might not be same as a cycle.

Comment: AFAIK graph theory terminology is not altogether standardised.  If you are reading a book you need to check where the definition is given.  If you are studying a course you should ask your teacher.  If you are writing an article you should choose whatever you want and make sure you explain it clearly.  FWIW I would say the answer to the question in your title is: yes.

Comment: @David In the text book, after giving some examples of cycle, an example of a loop is given later. No where it is mentioned to be a cycle. So I will keep them separate for this textbook. Textbook is "An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata" by Peter Linz 5th edition. chapter 1.

Comment: Does the book give a definition of a cycle as well as the examples?

Comment: @David It says: It defines a walk as a sequence of edges. A walk with no edges repeated is called a path. A walk from vi to itself with no repeated edges is called a cycle with base vi. Then the examples in a graph which contains loop but the examples don't mention any loop as a cycle. "Finally, an edge from a vertex to itself is called a loop. There is loop on vertex v3". Seems to me that they are different things in the context of this book.

Comment: Then it seems clear that a loop **is** a cycle: it is a sequence of edges from $v$ to $v$ with no repeated edges.

Comment: @David Yes. I concluded the same after reading it again. I need to improve reading things properly.

Comment: @David your answer is hidden in the comments - it would be good if you post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

*(Posting this as an answer because there was a suggestion that it should not remain as just a comment.)*

In a comment, OP quotes the definition from textbook: a walk from $v_i$ to itself with no repeated edges is called a cycle with base $v_i$.

Therefore, it seems clear that a loop **is** a cycle: it is a sequence of edges from $v$ to $v$ with no repeated edges.